# What is the result of multiplying $\sin x . \cos y$?

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

$$A = 9\sin^2x -6\sin x + 25\cos^2y - 20\cos y$$
For the minimum value of the $A$, What is the result of multiplying $\sin x . \cos y$?

I'm stuck at this question.

Regards,

Comment: I had mistaken something.See for the new, please.

Comment: Introduce two new variables $u=\sin x$, $v=\cos x$, so $A=9u^2-6u+25v^2-20v$, and $u,v\in[-1,1]$, find the minima of $9u^2-6u$ and $25v^2-20v$ in those intervals, finally $\sin x\cos y=uv$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
A=(3\sin x-1)^2+(5\cos y-2)^2-5.
$$
Hence the minimum of $A$ is obtained for $\sin x=1/3$ and $\cos y=2/5$.